# Symfony how to internationalize custom error pages

Tags: symfony, internationalization, custom-error-pages

I'm creating custom error pages for the 404 and 500 error in my Symfony project. I would like to know how to internationalize those pages.

What I mena by thta is that I already know how to use {% trans %} in my twig and how to create the file whit the translated texte. What I

Usally, my urls look like that: kevinduguay.ca/en/.....  but in the case of an error page, /en might not be there, but I still need to find in what language I should siplay the page. Maybe the language of the country?

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by following this [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html), you can find current local in error page by:
    $request->getLocal();

Although you dont nedd to this, trans() method detect current local

Comment: Will the current local change according to the country, or will it always be the default one? I would like that the language change automatically according to the country, is it duable?